# Localhost not recognized

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line-interface, localhost

For some reason my localhost is not recognized.

I have this in my hosts file as I've always had:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

I did do a flushdns, not sure if that caused it.  Then I tried a /registerdns in the command prompt.

I still have the same issue.

Comment: what did you do to know localhost is not recognized?

Comment: If you ping localhost do you get 127.0.0.1?

Comment: You didn't mention what web server you are using - did you install Apache or IIS?

Comment: in fact he didn't even mention if he was accessing a web server at all.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the problem was resource based in terms of localhost not recognizable across the entire PC..but that was not really the problem it turnes out.  The problem was IIS.  I uninstalled and re-installed and it's fine now.  No clue how this could have happened or what the problem was with IIS

Answer (score 0):

Well, as my comment is not answered I try it with guessing:

Maybe you tried "localhost" in your browser? Then you need a running webserver. Maybe you don't have one?

Did you try

```
ping localhost
```

- which IP address is resolved?
- Is that also not working?